# Regular expression that matches Strings with the same amount of a's as z's and b's as y's

Tags: regex

I'm currently working through a book on regular expressions, and one of the practice problems is to write a regular expression that match Strings that have the same number of a's as z's and b's as y's. I came up with the following regular expression so far.

```
^(?=[^az]*([az][^az]*[az][^az]*)*$)(?=[^by]*([by][^by]*[by][^by]*)*$).*$
```

The issue with this is that it incorrectly matches when a's and z's are even and b's and y's are even (i.e. azzz would match, but has more z's than a's).  Is there a way to modify my regular expression to match correctly or am I pursuing the wrong approach?

Comment: What tool/language do you use for your tests? Are `A` and `Z` always ordered (`AAAZZZ`) or can they be mixed up (`AZZAAZA`)? This doesn't really sound like a task one would use regex for.

Comment: I am using the following to test: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/voyrhI/1).  The A's and Z's and B's and Y's can be all mixed up per the book examples.

Comment: Does the book cover recursive expressions?

Comment: By a strict definition of "regular expression", this is not possible - regular expressions are memoryless, and so they cannot count instances of subpatterns or literals, nor can they compare counts. However, some extended language constructs (e.g. PCREs or "perl compatible regular expressions") can do this sort of thing, but they are not really "regular expressions" - they're considerably more than that.

Answer (score 1):

With some regex engines, you can use pre-defined [subroutines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to (clumsily) [define context-free grammars](https://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html), though the syntax varies from engine to engine and isn't standardized. Observe (still incomplete, but getting there):

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?'all'(?&az)|(?&by)|(?&abzy)|(?&bayz))
    (?'az'a(?&all)*z|z(?&all)*a)
    (?'by'b(?&all)*y|y(?&all)*b)
    (?'abzy'
        a(?&all)*b(?&all)*z(?&all)*y|
        a(?&all)*y(?&all)*z(?&all)*b|
        z(?&all)*b(?&all)*a(?&all)*y|
        z(?&all)*y(?&all)*a(?&all)*b
    )
    (?'bayz'
        b(?&all)*a(?&all)*y(?&all)*z|
        b(?&all)*z(?&all)*y(?&all)*a|
        y(?&all)*a(?&all)*b(?&all)*z|
        y(?&all)*z(?&all)*b(?&all)*a
    )
)

^(?&all)+$
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zFlP6i/7)

What this does is define a set of subpatterns and apply them recursively. Using the `^` and `$` anchors in the actual "pattern" makes sure that the entire string matches them. Simplicity itself.

Though, if you actually do something like this in a production environment, someone is liable to come shoot you when they find it.

Comment: Your `abzy` named group is missing variations starting with `b` or `y`, so `bzya` isn't working at the moment. Also `abbzyy` isn't working atm.

Comment: @SebastianProske Can't we apply a map function on each line and spit the output to another file with line number? Wouldn't that be more easy than writing a regular expression that will defy Einstein's Theory of Relativity?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: I'm mostly just doing it for the intellectual challenge rather than any real attempt at an answer. I know this is insane - that's what makes it fun :P

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Oops. mentioned different Sebastian above :P When you are done implementing let us know. We will make a frame of it and hang it in the museum for school childrens to look and wonder :P